# Why Stub Runner is not booting up a Wiremock server in the Classpath mode?

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to run some tests in my consumer application using Spring Cloud Contract's Stub Runner.

I have noticed that when the stubsMode property is set to `LOCAL`.

```
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(
        stubsMode = StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.LOCAL,
        ids = "com.example:spring-cloud-contract-producer:+:stubs:8090")
```

my build is successful because an embedded Wiremock instance boots up and listens in that port.

However, if I change the stubsMode property to `CLASSPATH`, my build fails because the test cannot establish a connection at that port.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8090/validate/prime-number": Connect to localhost:8090 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:8090 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

According to the [docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.1.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__spring_cloud_contract_stub_runner.html#_stub_downloading), this should only affect how the stubs are downloaded:

> StubRunnerProperties.StubsMode.CLASSPATH (default value) - will pick
>   stubs from the classpath

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Do you have a jar with stubs under `META-INF/com.example/spring-cloud-contract-producer/` on the classpath ?

Comment: I just checked and I don't find any JAR under that path. Can this be related to how did I include the producer dependency in the consumer project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you turn on the classpath mode then, as the name suggests, you need to have the dependencies on your classpath. The jar with the stubs needs to contain a predefined structure described in the docs. In general, in your case, it would contain a `META-INF/com.example/spring-cloud-contract-producer/mappings` folder with WireMock stubs inside it. If you don't have the producer stubs on your classpath then the classpath mode will not work.

Comment: Indeed, I was missing the `<classifier>stubs<classifier>` in my dependency declaration. However, I think the console's output could be more explicit. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you look at the output you'll see that it says that it can't find the stub at a given location and it then continues to the next mode until it reaches the end.

Comment: In my case, the log said:
`Will download stubs from classpath`, and then 
`Unpacked files for [com.example:spring-cloud-contract-producer:+] to folder [/var/folders/p5/2y1h50pn43l4vf67f_fbs9hc0000gn/T/classpath-stubs-1583254307238-0]`, followed by 
`Started stub server for project [com.example:spring-cloud-contract-producer:+:stubs] on port -1`

Comment: Oh I see. The -1 means that there were no stubs. Indeed the message could be better. Can you open an issue?